# Get rownames of a reactive data frame in R shiny and create a date range slider

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have a dataframe with a time series as index. The data in the data frame are updated by a dashboard action (e.g. a download button) and therefore the dataframe is reactive. With a slider I want to be able to select only certain rows of the dataframe. The min max values of the slider therefore refer to the rownames of the reactive data frame. So far I am not able to get this implemented. Below the code. The `if(0)` part in the SERVER section is the one I am talking about. Any help appreciated.

```
require(shiny)

AquireData <- function(){
  # In this function the data are created
  df <- data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:50,1000,rep=TRUE)))
  rownames(df)  <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2012-05-15 07:00"), 
                       to = as.POSIXct("2019-05-17 18:00"), by = "min")[0:dim(df)[1]]
  names(df) <- c('A','B','C')
  return (df)
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  # App title
  titlePanel("my dashboard"),

  # define stuff for the sidebar (buttons, selectlists etc.). These items will
  # be displayed for all panels
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("Button_GetAndUpdate", "Update data"),
      sliderInput("start_end_dates", "Date range", min =0, max=0, value=1)
    ),

    # Main panel. Here you can display your graphs, plots and tables
    mainPanel("observed data", tableOutput("rawdata"))      

  )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  # When the app is called an update of the data is drawn
  df_data <- reactive({AquireData()})

  # Check what the update button is doing. If its getting pressed pull and update
  observeEvent (input$Button_GetAndUpdate,{df_data <<- reactive({AquireData()})})  


  # set date range slider values using the dates from the data frame index
  if(0){
    updateSliderInput(session, "start_end_dates",
                      label = "Date range",
                      min = as.POSIXct(min(rownames(df_data())),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz=""),
                      max = as.POSIXct(max(rownames(df_data())),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="")
    )
  }
  # get the head of the dataframe
  data_head <- reactive({
    input$Button_GetAndUpdate
    isolate({
      head(df_data())
    })
  })

  output$rawdata <- renderTable({
    data_head()
  })   
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
runApp("Header_dashboard")
```

Comment: you probably want to look at dateRangeInput() and maybe shinyTime::timeInput()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `shinyWidgets::sliderTextInput` and `shinyWidgets::updateSliderTextInput` respectively instead of `sliderInput`for this:

```r
shinyWidgets::updateSliderTextInput(
  session, "start_end_dates",
  choices = rownames(df_data())
)
```

That means for your app:

```r
require(shiny)

AquireData <- function(){
  # In this function the data are created
  df <- data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:50,1000,rep=TRUE)))
  rownames(df)  <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2012-05-15 07:00"), 
                       to = as.POSIXct("2019-05-17 18:00"), by = "min")[0:dim(df)[1]]
  names(df) <- c('A','B','C')
  return (df)
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  # App title
  titlePanel("my dashboard"),

  # define stuff for the sidebar (buttons, selectlists etc.). These items will
  # be displayed for all panels
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("Button_GetAndUpdate", "Update data"),
      shinyWidgets::sliderTextInput(
        "start_end_dates", 
        label = "Time range",
        choices = c(as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 12:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2019-12-31 14:00:00")), 
      )
    ),

    # Main panel. Here you can display your graphs, plots and tables
    mainPanel("observed data", tableOutput("rawdata"))      

  )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  # When the app is called an update of the data is drawn
  df_data <- reactive({AquireData()})

  # Check what the update button is doing. If its getting pressed pull and update
  observeEvent (input$Button_GetAndUpdate,{df_data <<- reactive({AquireData()})})  


  # set date range slider values using the dates from the data frame index
  observe({
    shinyWidgets::updateSliderTextInput(
      session, "start_end_dates",
      choices = rownames(df_data())
    )
  })
  # get the head of the dataframe
  data_head <- reactive({
    input$Button_GetAndUpdate
    isolate({
      head(df_data())
    })
  })

  output$rawdata <- renderTable({
    data_head()
  })   
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```